# Possible for my vba code more compact and simplified

Tags: excel, vba

My vba code below to check on the userform textbox for any duplicate data on 3 rows. Once duplicate found, it will notified user and select entire row of the duplicate data. Its working and get job done. But, seems like the code quite long and repetitive. Is it possible to simplified and make my code more compact? Im still learning with vba code and dont know much about more advance function to get more compact code. Thank you.

```
Private Sub ISBNTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim ISBN
    Dim FoundISBN As Range
    Dim Search As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("booklist")
    Search = ISBNTextBox.Text
    Set FoundISBN = ws.Columns(5).Find(Search, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    ISBN = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("E:E"), Me.ISBNTextBox)
    If ISBN > 0 Then
        ISBN_checker.Caption = "Duplicate" & " " & FoundISBN.Address
        FoundISBN.EntireRow.Select
    Else
        ISBN_checker.Caption = ChrW(&H2713)
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub TitleTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim Title
    Dim FoundTitle As Range
    Dim Search As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("booklist")
    Search = TitleTextBox.Text
    Set FoundTitle = ws.Columns(2).Find(Search, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    Title = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("B:B"), Me.TitleTextBox)
    If Title > 0 Then
        Title_checker.Caption = "Duplicate" & " " & FoundTitle.Address
        FoundTitle.EntireRow.Select
    Else
        Title_checker.Caption = ChrW(&H2713)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CallNoTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim CallNo
    Dim FoundCallNo As Range
    Dim Search As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("booklist")
    Search = CallNoTextBox.Text
    Set FoundCallNo = ws.Columns(6).Find(Search, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    CallNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("F:F"), Me.CallNoTextBox)
    If CallNo > 0 Then
        CallNo_checker.Caption = "Duplicate" & " " & FoundCallNo.Address
        FoundCallNo.EntireRow.Select
    Else
        CallNo_checker.Caption = ChrW(&H2713)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If you have working code that you're just trying to get help improving, you should ask on [codereview.se] instead - that's exactly the reason it was created. This site is for questions about code you can't get working.

Comment: Ok, noted. Thank you. Ill ask there instead

Comment: You should delete it here also. Posting the same question on multiple sites is highly discouraged. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: Not actually. I also recently was made aware of it. It is on topic for both sites. :) You may want to see [Please stop redirecting performance problems to Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388864/please-stop-redirecting-performance-problems-to-code-review) and [Performance question - Stack Overflow or Code Review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300981/performance-question-stack-overflow-or-code-review) and [Guidance on migrating questions to Code Review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348395/guidance-on-migrating-questions-to-code-review)

Comment: @KenWhite Since you have enough reputation, you will be able to see the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390803/is-this-question-on-topic-for-code-review) that I had asked (now deleted)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: The policy is extremely unclear. Based on the second link you posted, there appears to be absoltely no reason for [codereview.se] to exist at all, as nothing that is relevant to ask there is off-topic here. It would appear that SO should adopt a clear set of guidelines and enforce them, instead of the vacillating back and forth about what should/shouldn't/might be/maybe should/who knows that is in place now. It's difficult enough now to do anything right here, and conflicting or confusing guidance from moderators and staff doesn't help.

Comment: I find the SO/CR split to be pretty artificial - it's all "how do I write better [VBA]" to some lesser or larger extent.  Looking at the VBA tag on CR it's pretty meagre volume-wise, so why not just leave them here - are the audiences really that different?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be moved to code Review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of repetition there, with a limited number of variable parts, so refactor the common code into a separate Sub and parameterize it.

Simpler:

```
Private Sub ISBNTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    DupCheck ISBNTextBox.Text, 5, ISBN_checker    
End Sub

Private Sub TitleTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    DupCheck TitleTextBox.Text, 2, Title_checker    
End Sub

Private Sub CallNoTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    DupCheck CallNoTextBox.Text, 6, CallNo_checker    
End Sub

Sub DupCheck(txt, ColNo As Long, theLabel As Object)
    Dim m
    With Worksheets("booklist")
        m = Application.Match(txt, .Columns(ColNo), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then '<-Fixed
            theLabel.Caption = "Duplicate" & " " & .Cells(m, ColNo).Address
            .Rows(m).Select
        Else
            theLabel.Caption = ChrW(&H2713)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Search = ISBNTextBox.Text`, so

```
Set FoundISBN = ws.Columns(5).Find(Search, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
```

and

```
ISBN = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range("E:E"), Me.ISBNTextBox)
```

are being used for the same thing. You can rewrite your code as

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ISBNTextBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Dim FoundISBN As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("booklist")
    ISBN_checker.Caption = ChrW(&H2713) '<~~ Set this as default value

    Set FoundISBN = ws.Columns(5).Find(What:=ISBNTextBox.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    '~~> Check if find returned anything
    If Not FoundISBN Is Nothing Then
        ISBN_checker.Caption = "Duplicate" & " " & FoundISBN.Address
        FoundISBN.EntireRow.Select
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note**: When using `.Find` remember 2 things

1. Excel remembers `.Find`'s last settings and  hence to avoid any confusion, use all parameters of it.
2. Always check whether `.Find` returned something or not before you try and use it else you will get "Run Time Error 91 - Object Variable or With  block variable  not set" error